# Rendering taking too much time Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular js in front end to load data to HTML. In my page index.html. I have dropdown to show a list from a local file which has names(around 4000). On page load I am calling get_all_names functions to load them.

```
$scope.get_all_names = function() {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'get_all_names.json'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.names_arr=data;
                    console.log("done");
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {          
            });
    }
```

I get an almost immediate response as done is printed in the console within  a second and $scope.names_arr is loaded immediately but a then just to render it to front end, it's taking around 20-30 secs by hanging the complete page for the same duration.

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select id="name_sel" class="form-control" ng-model="search_query.name">
          <option value="">-- Choose a Name --</option>
          <option ng-repeat="item in names_arr track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
    </div><!--/col-->
```

Please help me figure out why it's taking time to render it?

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your console, how long does the request take ?

Comment: it would be good, if you can create a plunker,http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @MartijnWelker  
It's showing a blue line from around 1700ms to a red line 2700ms, so I guess it's approx 1000ms.

Comment: Just a tip, don't use the success and error functions, they've been deprecated.